# Query causing sql injection issue

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sqlcommand, format-string

```cs
Type entryEntityType = entry.Entity.GetType();
string tableName = GetTableName(entryEntityType);
string primaryKeyName = GetPrimaryKeyName(entryEntityType);
string deletequery = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET IsDeleted = 1 WHERE {1} = @id", tableName, primaryKeyName);         
    
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(deletequery, new SqlParameter("@id", entry.OriginalValues[primaryKeyName]));
```

After running the sonar scan above query is giving a security hotspot for sql injection.How can this be handled?

Comment: You should use SQL parameters for every parameter (denoted with @ prefix) to avoid SQL injection. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: If possible, switch to EF 7 - it has the ability to perform updates directly in the DBMS. / Look at [Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/). Some of them allow you to perform updates efficiently, without loading entities to the client. I recommend linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore.

Comment: @Zserbinator the two values that are inserted through string.Format *cannot* be sent as parameters. The one value that can be a parameter *is* one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like table name and primary key name are dependent on user input, so I would suppress the Sonar error around this code. If you insist on fixing it you can do something like this (pseudo code):

Do this once, if you will, make it static:

```cs
var deleteQueries = new Dictionary<Type, string>();
foreach (Type entryEntityType in AllEntityTypes) // I don't know how you will get all entities
{
    string tableName = GetTableName(entryEntityType);
    string primaryKeyName = GetPrimaryKeyName(entryEntityType);
    string deletequery = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET IsDeleted = 1 WHERE {1} = @id", tableName, primaryKeyName);         
    deleteQueries.Add(entryEntityType, deleteQuery);
}
```

When executing delete do this:

```cs
Type entryEntityType = entry.Entity.GetType();
string deleteQuery = deleteQueries[entryEntityType];
string primaryKeyName = GetPrimaryKeyName(entryEntityType);
Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(deletequery, new SqlParameter("@id", entry.OriginalValues[primaryKeyName]));
```

As I said, I would just suppress the error.

Answer (score 1):

Also when injecting identifiers into dynamic SQL for SQL Server, you should sanitize the string by using a delimited identifier.

In TSQL you do this with the [QUOTENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function, and here's a C# version of it.

```
private static string QuoteName(string identifier)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(identifier.Length + 3, 1024);
    sb.Append('[');
    foreach (var c in identifier)
    {
        if (c == ']')
            sb.Append(']');
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    sb.Append(']');
    return sb.ToString();
}
```